# Cross domain - REST API

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I am using a REST API to request a JSON file and then using it in a tool in JS.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
$.getJSON(sourcefilename, function(http://restapi/myjson, status, xhr) {
```

I always receive an error due to the cross domain reuqest:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://restapi/myjson. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

I've read a lot of topics and tried a few things but I can't get around it, I was hoping someone could help me.

I am using APACHE with easyphp currently.
The API is JIRA REST API if that can help

Thanks

---

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
Order deny,allow
allow from 127.0.0.1
deny from all

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html
Those are the steps you'll need to undergo to enable CORS on your apache server.  You can see the browsers that support CORS here: http://enable-cors.org/client.html.

Comment: Thanks I tried first step and added "Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" " to .htaccess file in easyphp (devserver 14.1)  Then i retsarted apache but it did not work. I'm not sure about the next steps in the article, can you provide guidance please?

Comment: Can you post your .htaccess file without any sensitive information (if there is any)

Comment: Order deny,allow
allow from 127.0.0.1
deny from all

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Comment: Here is my .htaccess file:

    Order deny,allow
    allow from 127.0.0.1
    deny from all

    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"